# Perl map function not working

Tags: perl, paste, filehandle, initialization

i have a problem. This perl program should open all files and map them together, something similiar to paste command in unix system.

```
my @files;
for (@fileList ? @fileList : qw(-)) {
open  $files[@files], '<', $_; #}
}
while (grep defined, (my @lines = map {scalar <$_>;} @files)) {
    chomp @lines;
    print join("\t", @lines), "\n";
}
```

The problem is that, when it comes to two different files like

```
One 
Two 
Three
```

And:

```
Apple
Banana
Orange
Kiwi
```

It throws me an error of uninitialized value.

```
Use of uninitialized value $lines[0] in chomp 
Use of uninitialized value $lines[0] in join
```

Also same error vice versa, when files are Apple,Banana.. and One two three.

Thank you in advance

Comment: @TLP: it isn't undefined (arrays are never undefined) and referring to the element after the last is exactly what the code is designed to do

Comment: The title is misleading. `map` works perfectly fine. The error is in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that since your files have a different length, you will get some undefined values in your `@lines` array. You cannot filter them out in the while condition, but you can filter them out afterwards, inside the loop:

```
while (grep defined, (my @lines = map {scalar <$_>;} @files)) {
    @lines = map defined($_) ? $_ : "", @lines;
```

This will replace undefined values with the empty string, removing any `uninitialized` warnings for those values, while keeping your tabs correctly aligned.

Note that your code actually does what it is meant to do, because `undef` will stringify to the empty string. It is only because you have warnings on that you get the warnings about it. However, it is a very good idea to have warnings on, so errors such as this can be found and fixed properly.

You should note that using `open` without checking its return value is not a good idea, unless you explicitly handle the failed cases. The proper way is to do this:

```
open $files[@files], '<', $_ or die $!;
```

For simplicity one can also use

```
use autodie;
```

The [`autodie`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autodie) module will produce fatal errors for critical function calls such as `open`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Perl v5.10 or later installed (and you really should, as it is five years old now) then you can use the `//` (defined-or) operator to substitute a null string for `undef` after the end of the files. It will also impose scalar context on its operands, so there is no need to use the `scalar` operator. In addition you must substitute the `length` operator for `defined`, resulting in this code

```
while (grep length, (my @lines = map { <$_> // '' } @files)) {
    chomp @lines;
    print join("\t", @lines), "\n";
}
```